# php trying to adding time to a variable in sql

Tags: php, sql

Time:

```
<?php echo date("h:i A", (strtotime($row_AllEvents['event_time'])));
```

I have this time in php for certain events and each event also has a specific limit. 
What I want to do is add the limit to the `event time` and output it

the limit is stored within a sql database

```
like time =8 limit = 3  //output 8 - 11
```

This is what i have tried:

Time:

```
<?php echo date("h:i A", (strtotime($row_AllEvents['event_time'])+$duration));
```

Prints out:

Description:web
Date:September 10th, 2009
Time:12:00 AM
Location:canto
Duration:24

Description:dave
Date:June 6th, 2013
Time:02:00 AM
Location:php 123
Duration:7

Description:kajhdgfajhsdgfkjahsgdfkjahsgdfkajhsgdfkajhsgdfkajhsgdkfjhagsdkjfhagsdjf
Date:September 12th, 2013
Time:08:00 AM
Location:funny
Duration:45

Description:jack
Date:April 15th, 2014
Time:01:00 AM
Location:canto
Duration:8

Description:mickey
Date:April 15th, 2014
Time:04:00 AM
Location:canto
Duration:9

Description:high
Date:April 15th, 2014
Time:03:00 PM
Location:canto
Duration:9

Description:george
Date:April 17th, 2014
Time:03:00 AM
Location:canto
Duration:9

Description:minnie
Date:April 17th, 2014
Time:08:00 AM
Location:canto
Duration:8

Description:donald
Date:May 23rd, 2020
Time:04:12 AM
Location:canto
Duration:12

Comment: can you show the data that is returned by echo, and $duration, and event_time

Comment: Description:web 
Date:September 10th, 2009
Time:12:00 AM
Location:canto                                     
Duration:24

Comment: Please add it to the question, not the comments

Comment: Trying t get it where it adds diration t the time so 1 am woild become 9 am for Jack and so on

Comment: try `date('h:i A', strtotime($row_AllEvents['event_time'] . ' +' . $duration . ' hours'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You need to actually add the time in seconds to your value because that's the time the date function understands.

I assume your $duration is a time in minutes, so you convert that to seconds by multiplying by 60. Or if it is hours, by 60 again.

```
echo date("h:i A", strtotime($row_AllEvents['event_time']));
echo ' to ';
echo date("h:i A", strtotime($row_AllEvents['event_time']) + ( $duration * 60 )  );
```